# Include Doctrine2 in PHP class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I started with Doctrine2 usage in my projects. Howevery, I don't understand something. Normally, I am working with PHP classes and my problem is:

```
require_once 'bootstrap.php';
class test {

   public function addEmployee($name, $lastname) {
          $emp = new Employee();
          $emp->name = $name;
          ... other code
          $entityManager->persist($emp);
          $entityManager->flush();
   }

}
```

Gives error that entuty manager is noc declared as variable. But, when I include bootstrap.php in function, it works. Like this:

```
class test {

   public function addEmployee($name, $lastname) {

          require_once 'bootstrap.php';

          $emp = new Employee();
          $emp->name = $name;
          ... other code
          $entityManager->persist($emp);
          $entityManager->flush();
   }

}
```

I think it will be really slow if I include that in each function, so my question is: Is there any other way to include 'bootstrap.php' for all functions in class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dependency injection. For example

```
class Test {
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager) {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function addEmployee($name, $lastname) {
        // snip

        $this->em->persist($emp);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}

require_once 'bootstrap.php';
$test = new Test($entityManager);
```